# WAMP: httpd.exe -t prints nothing

Tags: apache, wampserver

My `httpd.conf` has errors but `httpd -t` does not print anything,

From the output of `httpd -k install`, it clearly pointed out that `httpd.conf` has errors in it.

[image]

But `httpd -t` does not print anything, what could be the problem here?

I'm trying to figure out the exact error of the conf file, and fix it.

Comment: The `httpd -k install` **will have installed a second instance of Apache** That is BOUND TO CONFUSE

Comment: Run `services.msc` and see if you have a `wampapache` AND an `Apache` service installed please

Comment: Then use `sc DELETE Apache`

Answer (score 0):

WAMPServer installs Apache as part of its initial installation, unless you mess up the install. The most likely reason being if you dont run the install "as an Administarator".

It installs Apache with the name `wampapache` or `wampapache64`.

Your attempt to maually install Apache will have installed another Apache service with the default name of `Apache` So now you have 2 Apache services running. (Never a good idea)

Also, if you wish to unregister the Apache service or re-register the Apache service there is a menu item on the wampmanager that will do this correctly for you.

```
left click wampmanager->Apache->Service Administration->Remove Service
```

or

```
left click wampmanager->Apache->Service Administration->Install Service
```

I suggest you remove the Apache service you have attempted to register. And use the wampmanager menus to do these tasks for you

Comment: This has nothing to do with services, I'm trying to figure out which part of httpd.conf is incorrect, e.g syntax error

Comment: Sorry about that, I posted `httpd -k install` to show prove that httpd.conf has errors

Comment: But in fact it does not show that at all. Read the message! It says _"Errors repported here must be corrected before the service can be started"_ **But no errors are reported**